# Incremental search in Idea the word under cursor

Tags: search, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, incremental-search

I would like to search in current file the word under cursor like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, except manually selecting current word? Is there alike keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - [*Find Next*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-word-at-caret.html)
Unfortunately, I have failed to find any keyboard shortcut for *Find Previous* shortcut.

Comment: Thank you. Ctlr-F3 starts the search, and a subsequent Shift-F3 will go to the previous occurrence. That is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are looking to do when you say "manually selecting current word", but <kbd>F3</kbd> (Next) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (previous) will search for the word under the cursor. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (Extend selection) to select the word under the cursor. Finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will open the find/search tool. More options are listed in help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/search.html

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, if you first use the mouse or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to select the word, and then open the search bar using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, or search & replace using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, IDEA will populate the search field with the selected text.

Comment: Thank you! However, I would like to start search without preliminary selecting current word.